# I want to create a webscraper that will scrape html from angular website

Tags: c#, angular, web-scraping

I am working on a Web scraper that will scrape from angular website.

I am using HttpClient class for this purpose but instead of getting html tags in the body tag of the page I am getting `<ng-view> </ng-view>` tags.
Can anyone explain what is going on and how can i get HTML code instead of `ng-view` tags?

Comment: You're better off looking into browser automation tools such as Selenium. I've never used it, but, in theory, you would be able to use .NET to tell the browser to invoke certain actions like clicking elements and whatnot. Once the browser executes the JS call to populate the ng-view, you would then have access to the HTML inside.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this won't be possible. All you can "scrape" is the initial markup that is served to the browser. All other content will be obtained by running the JavaScript, which makes calls back to the server for additional data.

Unless you're prepared to write a complete, fully-functional JavaScript engine, I'd say that initial page is all you'll get.

Comment: Ok I did not know that